# `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(...)` produce a value outside of [0,1] unexpectedly

Tags: python, pdf, scipy

```
import scipy.stats
means = [2,2]
covariance = [[0.0020, 0.0008],
              [0.0008, 0.0020]]
scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(means, covaraince).pdf([2,2])
> 86.82613975535709
```

Two questions about the above code:

- In the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html#scipy.stats.multivariate_normal) the pdf function allows you to (re?) define the mean and covariance. I don't understand that, the mean and covariance was defined in `multivariate_normal(...)` already. Why re-define it in the pdf function?

  [image]
- Second, the result of the call to `pdf([2,2])` is well over 1, but a PDF must produce a result in the range `[0,1]`. I must misunderstand something here.

Comment: a PDF can in principle take *any* non-negative value, as long as it integrates to one. The result you are getting is correct.

Comment: Oh, duh moment, you're right, I got too used to looking at more normal Normals. You should post that as the answer, and thank you!

Comment: @Stelios I'll re-post your answer shortly, but it'd be better if you posted it. Thanks again for the help on this. Just cleaning up old threads today.

Comment: I want to do something similar. I want to get the probability that a sample e.g. `[2,2]` belongs to a given distribution? Should I use `pdf`or `cdf` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PDF can in principle take any non-negative value, as long as it integrates to one. The result you are getting is correct.

> Posted on behalf of @Stelios's answer in comments